# Very different I/O performance in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, performance

I'm a new user and my english is not so good so I hope to be clear.
We're facing a performance problem using large files (1GB or more) expecially (as it seems) when you try to grow them in size.

Anyway... to verify our sensations we tryed the following (on Win 7 64Bit, 4core, 8GB Ram, 32 bit code compiled with VC2008)

a) Open an unexisting file. Write it from the beginning up to 1Gb in 1Mb slots.
Now you have a 1Gb file.
Now randomize 10000 positions within that file, seek to that position and write 50 bytes in each position, no matter what you write.
Close the file and look at the results.
Time to create the file is quite fast (about *0.3"*), time to write 10000 times is fast all the same (about *0.03"*).

Very good, this is the beginnig.
Now try something else...

b) Open an unexisting file, seek to 1Gb-1byte and write just 1 byte.
Now you have another 1Gb file.
Follow the next steps exactly same way of case 'a', close the file and look at the results.
Time to create the file is the faster you can imagine (about *0.00009"*) but write time is something you can't believe.... ***about 90"!!!!!***
b.1) Open an unexisting file, don't write any byte.
Act as before, ramdomizing, seeking and writing, close the file and look at the result.
Time to write is long all the same:  ***about 90"!!!!!***

Ok... this is quite amazing. But there's more!

c) Open again the file you crated in case 'a', don't truncate it... randomize again 10000 positions and act as before. You're fast as before, about *0,03"* to write 10000 times.

This sounds Ok... try another step.

d) Now open the file you created in case 'b', don't truncate it... randomize again 10000 positions and act as before. You're slow again and again, but the time is reduced to... ***45"!!*** Maybe, trying again, the time will reduce.

I actually wonder why...
Any Idea?

The following is part of the code I used to test what I told in previuos cases (you'll have to change someting in order to have a clean compilation, I just cut & paste from some source code, sorry).
The sample can read and write, in random, ordered or reverse ordered mode, but write only in random order is the clearest test.
We tryed using std::fstream but also using directly CreateFile(), WriteFile() and so on the results are the same (even if std::fstream is actually a little slower).

Parameters for case 'a' => -f_tempdir_\casea.dat -n10000 -t -p -w
Parameters for case 'b' => -f_tempdir_\caseb.dat -n10000 -t -v -w
Parameters for case 'b.1' => -f_tempdir_\caseb.dat -n10000 -t -w
Parameters for case 'c' => -f_tempdir_\casea.dat -n10000 -w
Parameters for case 'd' => -f_tempdir_\caseb.dat -n10000 -w

Run the test (and even others) and see...

```
  // iotest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
  //

  #include <windows.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <set>
  #include <vector>
  #include "stdafx.h"

  double RealTime_Microsecs()
  {
     LARGE_INTEGER fr = {0, 0};
     LARGE_INTEGER ti = {0, 0};
     double time = 0.0;

     QueryPerformanceCounter(&ti);
     QueryPerformanceFrequency(&fr);

     time = (double) ti.QuadPart / (double) fr.QuadPart;
     return time;
  }

  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
     std::string sFileName ;
     size_t stSize, stTimes, stBytes ;
     int retval = 0 ;

     char *p = NULL ;
     char *pPattern = NULL ;
     char *pReadBuf = NULL ;

     try {
        // Default
        stSize = 1<<30 ; // 1Gb
        stTimes = 1000 ;
        stBytes = 50 ;

        bool bTruncate = false ;
        bool bPre = false ;
        bool bPreFast = false ;
        bool bOrdered = false ;
        bool bReverse = false ;
        bool bWriteOnly = false ;

        // Comsumo i parametri
        for(int index=1; index < argc; ++index)
        {
           if ( '-' != argv[index][0] ) throw ;
           switch(argv[index][1])
           {
           case 'f': sFileName = argv[index]+2 ;
              break ;
           case 's': stSize = xw::str::strtol(argv[index]+2) ;
              break ;
           case 'n': stTimes = xw::str::strtol(argv[index]+2) ;
              break ;
           case 'b':stBytes = xw::str::strtol(argv[index]+2) ;
              break ;
           case 't': bTruncate = true ;
              break ;
           case 'p' : bPre = true, bPreFast = false ;
              break ;
           case 'v' : bPreFast = true, bPre = false ;
              break ;
           case 'o' : bOrdered = true, bReverse = false ;
              break ;
           case 'r' : bReverse = true, bOrdered = false ;
              break ;
           case 'w' : bWriteOnly = true ;
              break ;
           default: throw ;
              break ;
           }
        }

        if ( sFileName.empty() )
        {
           std::cout << "Usage: -f<File Name> -s<File Size> -n<Number of Reads and Writes> -b<Bytes per Read and Write> -t -p -v -o -r -w" << std::endl ;
           std::cout << "-t truncates the file, -p pre load the file, -v pre load 'veloce', -o writes in order mode, -r write in reverse order mode, -w Write Only" << std::endl ;
           std::cout << "Default: 1Gb, 1000 times, 50 bytes" << std::endl ;
           throw ;
        }

        if ( !stSize || !stTimes || !stBytes )
        {
           std::cout << "Invalid Parameters" << std::endl ;
           return -1 ;
        }

        size_t stBestSize = 0x00100000 ;


        std::fstream fFile ;
        fFile.open(sFileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary|std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::in|(bTruncate?std::ios_base::trunc:0)) ;

        p = new char[stBestSize] ;
        pPattern = new char[stBytes] ;
        pReadBuf = new char[stBytes] ;
        memset(p, 0, stBestSize) ;
        memset(pPattern, (int)(stBytes&0x000000ff), stBytes) ;

        double dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;

        size_t stCopySize, stSizeToCopy = stSize ;

        if ( bPre )
        {
           do {
              stCopySize = std::min(stSizeToCopy, stBestSize) ;
              fFile.write(p, stCopySize) ;
              stSizeToCopy -= stCopySize ;
           } while (stSizeToCopy) ;
           std::cout << "Creating time is: " << xw::str::itoa(RealTime_Microsecs()-dTime, 5, 'f') << std::endl ;
        }
        else if ( bPreFast )
        {
           fFile.seekp(stSize-1) ;
           fFile.write(p, 1) ;
           std::cout << "Creating Fast time is: " << xw::str::itoa(RealTime_Microsecs()-dTime, 5, 'f') << std::endl ;
        }

        size_t stPos ;

        ::srand((unsigned int)dTime) ;

        double dReadTime, dWriteTime ;

        stCopySize = stTimes ;

        std::vector<size_t> inVect ;
        std::vector<size_t> outVect ;
        std::set<size_t> outSet ;
        std::set<size_t> inSet ;

        // Prepare vector and set
        do {
           stPos = (size_t)(::rand()<<16) % stSize ;
           outVect.push_back(stPos) ;
           outSet.insert(stPos) ;

           stPos = (size_t)(::rand()<<16) % stSize ;
           inVect.push_back(stPos) ;
           inSet.insert(stPos) ;
        } while (--stCopySize) ;

        // Write & read using vectors
        if ( !bReverse && !bOrdered )
        {
        std::vector<size_t>::iterator outI, inI ;
        outI = outVect.begin() ;
        inI = inVect.begin() ;
        stCopySize = stTimes ;
        dReadTime = 0.0 ;
        dWriteTime = 0.0 ;
        do {
           dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;
           fFile.seekp(*outI) ;
           fFile.write(pPattern, stBytes) ;
           dWriteTime += RealTime_Microsecs() - dTime ;
           ++outI ;

           if ( !bWriteOnly )
           {
              dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;
              fFile.seekg(*inI) ;
              fFile.read(pReadBuf, stBytes) ;
              dReadTime += RealTime_Microsecs() - dTime ;
              ++inI ;
           }
        } while (--stCopySize) ;
        std::cout << "Write time is " << xw::str::itoa(dWriteTime, 5, 'f') << " (Ave: " << xw::str::itoa(dWriteTime/stTimes, 10, 'f') << ")" <<  std::endl ;
        if ( !bWriteOnly )
        {
           std::cout << "Read time is " << xw::str::itoa(dReadTime, 5, 'f') << " (Ave: " << xw::str::itoa(dReadTime/stTimes, 10, 'f') << ")" << std::endl ;
        }
        } // End

        // Write in order
        if ( bOrdered )
        {
           std::set<size_t>::iterator i = outSet.begin() ;

           dWriteTime = 0.0 ;
           stCopySize = 0 ;
           for(; i != outSet.end(); ++i)
           {
              stPos = *i ;
              dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;
              fFile.seekp(stPos) ;
              fFile.write(pPattern, stBytes) ;
              dWriteTime += RealTime_Microsecs() - dTime ;
              ++stCopySize ;
           }
           std::cout << "Ordered Write time is " << xw::str::itoa(dWriteTime, 5, 'f') << " in " << xw::str::itoa(stCopySize) << " (Ave: " << xw::str::itoa(dWriteTime/stCopySize, 10, 'f') << ")" <<  std::endl ;

           if ( !bWriteOnly )
           {
              i = inSet.begin() ;

              dReadTime = 0.0 ;
              stCopySize = 0 ;
              for(; i != inSet.end(); ++i)
              {
                 stPos = *i ;
                 dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;
                 fFile.seekg(stPos) ;
                 fFile.read(pReadBuf, stBytes) ;
                 dReadTime += RealTime_Microsecs() - dTime ;
                 ++stCopySize ;
              }
              std::cout << "Ordered Read time is " << xw::str::itoa(dReadTime, 5, 'f') << " in " << xw::str::itoa(stCopySize) << " (Ave: " << xw::str::itoa(dReadTime/stCopySize, 10, 'f') << ")" <<  std::endl ;
           }
        }// End

        // Write in reverse order
        if ( bReverse )
        {
           std::set<size_t>::reverse_iterator i = outSet.rbegin() ;

           dWriteTime = 0.0 ;
           stCopySize = 0 ;
           for(; i != outSet.rend(); ++i)
           {
              stPos = *i ;
              dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;
              fFile.seekp(stPos) ;
              fFile.write(pPattern, stBytes) ;
              dWriteTime += RealTime_Microsecs() - dTime ;
              ++stCopySize ;
           }
           std::cout << "Reverse ordered Write time is " << xw::str::itoa(dWriteTime, 5, 'f') << " in " << xw::str::itoa(stCopySize) << " (Ave: " << xw::str::itoa(dWriteTime/stCopySize, 10, 'f') << ")" <<  std::endl ;

           if ( !bWriteOnly )
           {
              i = inSet.rbegin() ;

              dReadTime = 0.0 ;
              stCopySize = 0 ;
              for(; i != inSet.rend(); ++i)
              {
                 stPos = *i ;
                 dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;
                 fFile.seekg(stPos) ;
                 fFile.read(pReadBuf, stBytes) ;
                 dReadTime += RealTime_Microsecs() - dTime ;
                 ++stCopySize ;
              }
              std::cout << "Reverse ordered Read time is " << xw::str::itoa(dReadTime, 5, 'f') << " in " << xw::str::itoa(stCopySize) << " (Ave: " << xw::str::itoa(dReadTime/stCopySize, 10, 'f') << ")" <<  std::endl ;
           }
        }// End

        dTime = RealTime_Microsecs() ;
        fFile.close() ;
        std::cout << "Flush/Close Time is " << xw::str::itoa(RealTime_Microsecs()-dTime, 5, 'f') << std::endl ;

        std::cout << "Program Terminated" << std::endl ;

     }
     catch(...)
     {
        std::cout << "Something wrong or wrong parameters" << std::endl ;
        retval = -1 ;
     }

     if ( p ) delete []p ;
     if ( pPattern ) delete []pPattern ;
     if ( pReadBuf ) delete []pReadBuf ;

     return retval ;
  }
```

Comment: Have you measured the complete runtime of all the different tests? (Including the creation of the 1Gb file for case a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't flushing the changes, and you've got enough free ram to cache it, you are just measuring the speed of your ram.

Also, be aware that some filesystems support "holes", areas of a file which aren't allocated. If the filesystem has such support (I don't know whether any  do on Windows, but they may), then the test which does a "seek" to 1G then writes 1 byte, will create a file which is mostly a "hole", hence requires few blocks to be written.

Finally, you should repeat every test lots and lots of times, flushing the entire cache each time (this is possible without reboot on Windows using a sysinternals tool) and running on an otherwise idle machine with any on-access AV software disabled. If you see big discrepancies in the performance, something strange is happening.

---

Be absolutely sure that any writes done by the previous test are completely flushed to disc before beginning the next test, otherwise it will screw your data up completely.

Lastly, don't take any notice of performance data on a VM. Do all performance testing on real hardware if you want consistent results (EVEN if you are deploying into a VM).

Comment: +1. A cursory search shows that the default FS in windows NTFS does support "holes" in what their documentation defines as "Sparse File optimizations"

Answer (score 3):

It might well depend on the filesystem that you are using. I don't really know much about the NTFS filesystem, but many FS optimize away empty space in [sparse files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa365564), where empty space is defined as blocks in the file for which nothing was written. Note that reads will return 0 for these positions, but *nothing* was written.

The first test creates and allocates all required blocks in the file. Then the random modifications just modify the contents of already allocated blocks of disk. The rest of the tests create the file, but never actually write to it, so the FS might contain the size of the file but no allocated blocks. The test in this case has to seek, allocate a block from the disk to the file, initialize it all to 0s and then write the data. You can check the actual space allocated from the disk in all cases as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365276).

The third block of results 45", might as well be related to the random locations hitting a balance of allocated (fast writes) and unallocated (slow writes) blocks.

EDIT: It seems that NTFS does have this type of [Sparse File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Sparse_files) optimization.

Comment: GetCompressedFileSize() give me the same result in both case 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: I checked Sparse File documentation and used a "sparse_checker" utility that analyzes files to say if they're sparse and how many space can be saved.
I first thought that any file could be sparse, and NTFS decides on it's own how to act. But I was wrong.
You MUST request a file to be Sparse, or it behaves exaclty as any other file.  So... sparse file doesn't seem to be the cause of this behaviour

Answer (score 3):

It's all down to disk caching and file system structure. Some read/write operation will only need to operate on a cache if the data is already in there and be flushed later. Other operations must operate on the disk as the data is not in the cache and will be much slower.

The arrangement of blocks in the filesystem could also affect these things. In the extreme, adding that one byte to the GB file may cause a good portion of it to be moved on the disk. Other factors such as fragmentation, block size and the way read/writes are optimised and cached could cause the effects you see.